# Angular listen to function that returns some variable

Tags: angular, service, components

So I have a function in my service that's returning a value and I want my component to be listening to  the value and update it when it changes so I thought It would be a good idea to subscribe to it but it doesn't work as intended and doesn't update the value when it changes. Is there a different way to do this?

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.translateService.onLangChange.subscribe(() => this.getLocaleDateFormat());
  }

 getLocaleDateFormat(): Observable<string> {
   this.dateAdapter.setLocale(Languages[this.translateService.currentLang]);
   this.currLang = Languages[this.translateService.currentLang];
    console.log( 'get' + this.currLang);
    return of (this.currLang);

  }

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.localeDateAdapterService.getLocaleDateFormat().subscribe(currLang => this.currLang = currLang);
}
```

I don't need to know when it changes I just the value to update when it changes. Without using a timer and also without using OnLangChange as a trigger:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
 this.translateService.onLangChange.subscribe(() => this.localeDateAdapterService.getLocaleDateFormat().subscribe(currLang => this.currLang = currLang));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it as as a separate service called LocaleService. You somehow have to get the current language maybe from translate service or if you make it as a separate service that  handles it.

```
private onLanguageChange(lang: string): void {
        // To add another lang:
        // 1. add mapping from EMS language codes to Angular locale codes in the map at the bottom of this file
        // 2. register locale data, also at the bottom of this file
        const locale = Languages[lang];
        this.activeLocale.next(locale);
        this.dateAdapter.setLocale(locale);
        this.LW.log('Language change detected (current lang: ' + lang + '), setting locale to: ' + locale);
      }
    
      public getActiveLocale(): BehaviorSubject<string> {
        return this.activeLocale;
      }
    export const Languages = {
      'eng': 'en',
      'slk': 'sk',
      'cze': 'cs',
    };
    
    registerLocaleData(localeSk);
    registerLocaleData(localeCs);
```

this goes to the Component

```
this.localeService.getActiveLocale().subscribe(locale => this.currentLocale = locale));
```

Comment: Won't this create a circular dependency because of the the component needing the service and the service the component?

Answer (score 1):

Use a **subject** from /rxjs

```
// Service

language$ = new Subject<string>();

setLanguage(lang: string): void {
 this.language$.next(lang);
}


// Component

this.language$.subscribe((res: string) => {
 console.log(res);
});

this.languageSrv.setLanguage('en');
this.languageSrv.setLanguage('es');
this.languageSrv.setLanguage('it');
this.languageSrv.setLanguage('fr');

// 'en'
// 'es'
// 'it'
// 'fr'
```

always rememenber to unsubscribe